# UIImageView not shaping into a proper circle shape in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uistoryboard

I have a **UIImageView** inside a **TableViewCell** where I want to display the Image View into a Circle and have done some research online, but the **UIImageView** converts to a circular rectangular type instead.

**Here is the example issue:**

[image: Example Issue]
As you can see the Image is rounded but it's more like a rectangle circle rather than an actual circle which is what I want to achieve.

**Storyboard object placements**

[image: Storyboard Object Placements]

**Here's what I've tried doing**

- Setting both the **height** and **width** of the **UIImageView** to the same value
- Content Mode: Aspect Fill **(Was already enabled in storyboard)**
- **cellForRowAt** function - See code below

```
cell.backgroundImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.backgroundImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.backgroundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.backgroundImageView.frame.width / 2
```

Appreciate if the **Stackoverflow** community could help me on this mystery issue and show a normal circle instead.

**Edit: Added Constraints**

```
<constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="SN7-KQ-bLs" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="fnk-DG-TK8"/>

<constraint firstItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="IYt-ky-1cl" secondAttribute="trailing" id="0f0-6E-N9y"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="C1t-o2-7NZ" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="0oA-se-a9X"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="SN7-KQ-bLs" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="C1t-o2-7NZ" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="953-xq-W2Y"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="IYt-ky-1cl" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-3" id="BFj-p7-RM6"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="C1t-o2-7NZ" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="54" id="hVv-nQ-bAl"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="SN7-KQ-bLs" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="218" id="k47-df-sZ3"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="SN7-KQ-bLs" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" secondAttribute="top" id="sbF-ni-mJE"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="IYt-ky-1cl" secondAttribute="leading" id="uoy-hv-n5V"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="VVM-Vf-iwJ" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="C1t-o2-7NZ" secondAttribute="trailingMargin" id="xr8-93-737"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="SN7-KQ-bLs" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="7" id="ysw-uw-sXi"/>
```

Comment: You should not be doing it in `cellForRowAt`. You should instead do it on `init` and the `cornerRadius` should be applied in `layoutSubviews` method of your cell. Also, check if your constraints are broken. Would help if you showed your constraints as well.

Comment: Have you added aspect ratio constraint?

Comment: I think you can fix the height and width of the image eg. 70 each and then add a corner radius of width/2 will do the trick.

Comment: I've added a new Override function in my TableViewCell class with the cornerRadius moved and included inside of it. I've added an aspect ratio constraint (edited post - it's the first constraint). I've tried fixing both height and width to 70 as the corner radius will divide width by 2. Same problem still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your **`uitableViewCell`** class and use below code it works for me and will work for you.

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    backGroundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = backGroundImageView.frame.width / 2
    backGroundImageView.clipsToBounds = true
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    cell.backgroundImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.backgroundImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.backgroundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.backgroundImageView.frame.width / 2
 }
```

Try this in your tableviewcell class